# NullReferenceExecption although item is defined

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am currently working on an OPC AE Client for an alarm analyser tool. Unfortunately I have to explain what my tool does to explain the problem. Probably this list is not important for my problem but it explain the multi threading part which might be the root.

The Exception occurs in the if clause of the following code sample.

```
private bool areInSameGroup(ALARM_ITEM alarmItem, ALARM_ITEM groupCandidate)
{            
    // Check if those groups are the same one
    // if the items are part of the same alarmGroup, return true. 
    // The if clause compares the first Item of the alarmlist of a group
    // to check if the items are identically
    if (findAlarmGroup(alarmItem).AlarmList[0].uniqueIdentifier == 
        findAlarmGroup(groupCandidate).AlarmList[0].uniqueIdentifier)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The next sample contains the findAlarmGroup method to check whether there is a connection or not. The complete software runs for a few seconds but than The MessageBox appears and the Exeption is thrown. I am really sorry for all the code but is the only way to explain the problem. I am really stuck at the moment because from my point of view this Messagebox should never appear for every Alarm is assigned to a group in the beginning of the analysis class.

I would be really happy if anyone might take the hassle and have a look at my code.

```
// Method gets an AlarmItem and searches in every alarm group in 
// the AlarmGroupList
// for the uniqueIdentifier of the received alarmItem.
private ALARM_GROUP findAlarmGroup(ALARM_ITEM alarmItem)
{
    foreach (var alarmgroup in AlarmGroupList)
    {
        foreach (var groupedAlarm in alarmgroup.AlarmList)
        {
            if (groupedAlarm.uniqueIdentifier == alarmItem.uniqueIdentifier)
            {
                //return the found alarmgroup
                return alarmgroup;
            }
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("FEHLER");
    ALARM_GROUP noGroupFound = new ALARM_GROUP();
    return noGroupFound;
 }
```

- External Server Signal (OPC AE) raises Event (ca. every 2 seconds)
- Event calls for HandlingMethod and attaches OPC AE Data as a list
- HandlingMethod:
  Accesses a global list, merges the global one with the new one
  starts Task to run analyser with some global variables and the global list from above
  Analyser:
- Takes the alarms and several other methods, deletes some alarms based on a database and adds a global a number from
- a global counter to the alarms. Increases the numeber afterwards. In main algorithm searches for interrelations between alarms, groups them and returns a list of groups.

Details:

```
// new list for Alarm_Group. Contains the alarm groups
AlarmGroupList = new List<ALARM_GROUP>();

// Every Alarm gets it's own Alarm Group, everytime startAnalysis 
// is called
foreach (var AlarmItem in OnlineAlarmList)
{
    //Create new group of alarms
    ALARM_GROUP newgroup1 = new ALARM_GROUP();

    //Create List of alarms in this alarmgroup
    newgroup1.AlarmList = new List<ALARM_ITEM>();

    //Add the alarm item to the Alarmlist of the new alarm group
    newgroup1.AlarmList.Add(AlarmItem);

    //Add the alarm group to the overall AlarmGroupList
    AlarmGroupList.Add(newgroup1);    
}

// START 
// Run through all ALARM_ITEMs of the alarmevery log
foreach (var alarmItem in OnlineAlarmList)
{
    int counterRunner;

    // Take the Index of the currently analysed alarmItem, 
    // increase it by one and access the 
    // AlarmList with this index
    counterRunner = OnlineAlarmList.IndexOf(alarmItem) + 1;

    //Run through all rules of the RuleBase
    foreach (var rule in rulebase.RuleBaseList)
    {
        // Check if selected rule can be applied on selected 
        // ALARM_ITEM (itemA vs. ALARM_ITEM)
        if (rule.itemA == getAlarmType(alarmItem.AlarmTag))
        {
            //Check against any ALARM_ITEM in timeframe
            bool inTimeframe = true;

            ALARM_ITEM groupCandidate;


            while (inTimeframe)
            {
                // if the current alarm items has been compared to the 
                // last item in the list break the loop
                // and start with a new rule
                int counterRunnerInternal = counterRunner;

                if (counterRunnerInternal >= OnlineAlarmList.Count - 1)
                    break;

                // group candidate is the next alarm in the list, 
                // hence the current alarm of the foreach loop and the 
                // next alarm in the list are checked

                groupCandidate = OnlineAlarmList[counterRunnerInternal];

                // Check if startItem and Candidate are not already 
                // grouped together
                if (!areInSameGroup(alarmItem, groupCandidate))    
                    //
             }
         }
         else
         {
             inTimeframe = false;
         }

         counterRunnerInternal++;
     }
```

Comment: You have verified that AlarmList[0] contains something other than null, correct?  (via some way to print some property to the string or somesuch.)

Comment: It's fighting the symptoms, not the disease. If I add 
    if (findAlarmGroup(alarmItem).AlarmList[0] != null && findAlarmGroup(groupCandidate).AlarmList[0] != null)
there is no problem any more but also no results. At least it leads me to new problems to face.

Comment: ok, now it leads me to "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." in a different method. I will check this.

Comment: I wasn't saying you should necessarily always check.  I was saying it would be good for debugging to determine if it is truly null at that point.  But I'm glad you have something to follow up on, at least.

Comment: Hmm, sorry when my first answer sounded a bit rude, it was not meant to be. There is still a basic problem in my software that makes my grouping algorithm senseless. 
I am a bit confuses about the variable value when my program crashed because my Console tells me that Alarm Group 2195 and 2178 have been merged, the last value for the number of alarm groups is 437, the number of the alarms is 439 and my UI tells me the number has been decreased by 50%. Strange things going on...

Comment: Last answer for today: I probably found the problem by myself, at least one of the problems. One or more Lists are accessed by different threads at a time, reading and writing. Tomorrow morning I will study the C# in a Nutshell chapter about thread safety and locking...

Comment: Aha! That sounds like an excellent plan.  C# has great support for multithreading but you will need to understand the mechanisms it supplies!

Comment: Tried to make AlarmGroupList threadsafe now by lock(AlarmGroupList){...} in every method it is accessed but my problems still go on. I still have a NullReferenceExeption in findAlarmGroup and I don't get it why.